# две выборки + пагинация

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно, чтобы в общем списке объявлений (до 15 шт) всегда на первом месте выводились премиум-объявления, но только ограниченно (до 5 шт). Т.е. на странице может быть всего 20 объявлений.

1. сначала я попробовал сделать общую выборку с сортировкой по премиуму, но получилось не совсем то, т.к. будут все премиум первыми идти в выдаче.
2. решил сделать две отдельные выборки (`select count`) и результат (`select`) объединить (`array_merge`). Но столкнулся с проблемой пагинации, которую не пойму как решить: 
   допустим выборка премиум дала 10 страниц (9стр. по 5шт, 10я - 2шт), а обычная выборка дала 3 страницы.

На сайте я получаю готовые 3 страницы, на которых видно все как надо, но т.к. премиум заняло 10 страниц, то часть премиум уже потеряна.

Подскажите логику действий, а то запутался! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать UNION. Первый запрос с LIMIT 5.

```
(SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `is_premium` = 1 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `is_premium` = 0);
```